# ACL for Joomla Component

Tags: joomla2.5, acl, joomla-extensions, breezingforms

I have downloaded a 3rd party plugin for Joomla (Breezing Forms). I have created a new user for my Joomla instance who only has access to certain privileges. Breezing Forms is the only component they can use.

I have set these settings correctly from the super user, there is one action, "Configure" which I have set to "allow" for my specific user type.

Now when I log in as that user, I cannot see the components menu (I have disallowed all other components).

But if I navigate to the component:

http://domain.co.uk/administrator/index.php?option=com_breezingforms

Then I can access the page.

I have tried denying access, then trying to access the page and it rightfully prevents me from using it, so the ACL privileges are working, but there is an issue with it displaying in the menu.

I am using Joomla 2.5

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 1):

Usually a component has two permissions which deal with that kind of stuff.

- `core.manage` (Access Administration Interface) allows access to the component in the backend. This means the menu item is present in the Components menu.
- `core.admin` (Configure) allows to set the options for this component.

So make sure you have set the correct permissions in BreezingForms. You probably want to have `core.manage` (Access Administration Interface) and not the other one. Also if you set the Configure one, make sure you also enable the manage one. It doesn't make much sense otherwise.